# Magnet link intent: No activity found to handle intent

Tags: android, android-intent, magnet-uri

So I have a magnet link and I want to open it in the browser or Flud (exactly what happens when clicking a magnet link in the browser)

My code

```
class PartViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    var img_download = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_download) as ImageView
    var mcontext = itemView.context

    fun bind(part: PartData, clickListener: (PartData) -> Unit){
        img_download.setOnClickListener(){
            val uri = Uri.parse(magnetlink)
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
            mcontext.startActivity(intent)
```

My stack trace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=magnet:?xt=urn:btih:69C58E0...
```

I have tried `intent.setType("application/x-bittorrent")` with the same result. I do have a couple of applications capable of handling magnet links installed on my test device.

EDIT:

Comment: Hello! I have edited my post to show I am within the onClickListener of a view within a viewHolder

Comment: "I do have a couple of applications capable of handling magnet links installed on my test device" -- that may be true, but they do not appear to have an `<intent-filter>` for `ACTION_VIEW` and a `Uri` scheme of `magnet`. You could use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majeur.applicationsinfo) to see what `<intent-filter>` they do have.

Comment: Hello CommonsWare! Bought your books a couple of years ago, I'm still learning. :) The app you linked shows me that Flud does have an `intent-filter` with `data android:scheme="magnet"` and another with `data android:mimeType="application/x-bittorrent"`.

Comment: That `magnet` `Uri` structure is odd enough that it might break Android's `Uri` parsing and generating rules (query parameters with no host or path). Does the `Uri` in the error message exactly match the value that you are providing via `magnetlink`? Does the `<intent-filter>` with `android:scheme="magnet"` have an `<action>` for `android.intent.action.VIEW` or any other `<data>` elements in it?

Comment: I tried reducing the magnet link to its simplest form `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:<hash>` to insure the `Uri` does match the value of the error message, and it does, but I still get the error. As for the intent yes the action `android.intent.action.VIEW` is there. I don't understand what goes wrong.
https://imgur.com/a/h0gdRd2q

Comment: The image link in your comment is not working. If you could grab a screenshot of what that Application Info app is showing for the relevant manifest entry, add that to your question, and perhaps something in there will explain matters.

Comment: Sorry for the broken link https://dropmefiles.com/I3EGo

Comment: That link also does not appear to be working -- I get no response from the server.

Comment: https://ibb.co/fzPRg9 Hoping this one does it

Comment: OK, that loaded. The `<intent-filter>` looks simple enough, and the activity must be enabled as it is the launcher activity (you probably would have noticed if that were disabled). Try a `Uri` with just `magnet`, probably via `Uri.Builder` rather than `Uri.parse()`. See what happens with it in your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. If it launches Flud (which then complains about the `Uri` being invalid), then my guess is that the funky `Uri` syntax is confusing Android somewhere. If you still get `ActivityNotFoundException`, then I am out of ideas. You might also contact Flud for advice.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I found a workaround by using https://itorrents.org/ to get an http .torrent link instead of a magnet link. Not the prettiest solution but it seems to work.